# How to use different error bars for grouped data of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm having some trouble with error bars in python. I'm plotting the columns on a pandas dataframe grouped, so on this example dataframe:

```
unfiltered = [0.975,0.964,0.689,0.974]
filtered = [0.954,0.932,0.570,0.960]
index_df = ["Accuracy", "Recall", "Precision", "Specificity"]
column_names = ["Unfiltered", "With overhang filter"]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(unfiltered,filtered)),index=index_df,columns=column_names)
```

So my dataframe looks like this:

```
             Unfiltered  With overhang filter
Accuracy       0.975              0.954
Recall         0.964              0.932
Precision      0.689              0.570
Specificity    0.974              0.960
```

And I plot it with this following lines:

```
plt.style.use('ggplot')
ax = data_df.plot.bar(rot=0)
plt.show()
```

I get a figure like this:

[image: linked image]

Now I want to add error bars, but my problem is that I don't seem to be able to figure out how to get a different error value for **each** bar. I want to use the standard deviation and the values I have are different for each one of them (example: the std for both recalls shown is different). My problem is that if I add:

```
ax = data_df.plot.bar(rot=0, yerr=data_errors)
```

where data_errors is a list with the 8 standard deviations I get:

```
ValueError: The lengths of the data (4) and the error 8 do not match
```

It does work when data_errors has only 4 elements, but then it plots the same error bars for both accuracies, recalls, etc.

Can anyone help me to keep the data grouped by index like it is, but with different error bars for each value of the dataframe?

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to the user Quang Hoang I researched into `sns.barplot`. The solution to my problem was to create a dataframe (which I named `data_df`) like this:

```
      Indicator      Data       Class
0      Accuracy  0.966279  Unfiltered
1      Accuracy  0.981395  Unfiltered
2      Accuracy  0.989535  Unfiltered
3      Accuracy  0.975553  Unfiltered
4      Accuracy  0.961583  Unfiltered
5        Recall  0.954545  Unfiltered
...
35  Specificity  0.941176    Filtered
36  Specificity  0.953431    Filtered
37  Specificity  0.993865    Filtered
38  Specificity  0.946012    Filtered
39  Specificity  0.953374    Filtered
```

Followed by:

```
ax =  sns.barplot(x="Indicator", y= "Data",hue="Class", data=data_df, ci="sd")
```

This allowed me to create this figure:
[image]
where as you can see the error bars are different for each value, and also calculated automatically.

Comment: Did you calculate `data_df` and `data_errors` from another dataframe? If so, you can use `sns.barplot`.

Comment: No, I made them both from lists I calculated earlier in my script, but maybe I can assemble a dataframe and try sns.barplot (I've never used it and I'm somewhat new to python so I'm not sure I'll solved it but I've seen an example figure doing something very similar to what I want, thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

This might not be exactly what you're looking

```py
data_df.stack().plot.bar(yerr=data_errors)
```

Comment: That does allow me to plot the 8 different errors, but the data stops being grouped according to the dataframe index. I might use this eventually if I can't figure out how to make the data stay grouped but have 8 different error bars though